# Android AlertDialog Default Orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-orientation

I would like to change my Alert dialog default orientation to Landscape by default. I am not willing to handle the dialog orientation when the device orientation is changed.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MenuActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setTitle("EXIT")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            MenuActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    alert.show();
```

I am unable to find what specifically handle the default orientation of this dialog? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this method in your activity.

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested but may be it will works for you.

You Should have to Implement the Custom AlertDialogStyle and implement it in to your code.
See here: [for to make Custom Dialog](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/customize-alertdialog-theme)

And there in Style file, add properties like

```
<item name="android:orientation">landscape</item>
```

Hope it will works for you.

Enjoy Coding. . . . .